# Notice: Undefined variable: logger

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined variable: logger in .../application_bottom.php on line 20

```
if (!is_object($logger)) $logger = new logger;
```

I Solved this by

```
if (!is_object('logger')) $logger = new logger;
```

But why? can somebody explain this

Comment: Your solution is not right. it will always create a new object and place it inside $logger

Comment: You get the notice because `$logger` is not defined before you call it. Calling `is_object` on a string will always return false. A bad solution. You should do a `isset`.

Answer (score 1):

The following conditional:

```
if (!is_object('logger'))
```

basically asks "if the string 'logger' in an object.." which will always return false and is not the correct solution to your problem. you can use a combination of `isset()` and `is_object()` to achieve what you want:

```
if (!(isset($logger) && is_object($logger))) $logger = new logger;
```

You got your error because `$logger` wasn't defined when running `is_object()`, by cheking if `$logger` is set and using the `&&` operator you make sure that `is_object()` will not run if `isset()` returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements and background information. problem is solved.